# form-select not sending data

Tags: php, html, jquery, forms, bootstrap-5

I dont see the reason why one particular html field is not sending data.

My html:

```
<form  id="login_registro_form" role="form" method="post" action="./controllers/register.php">
        <div class="row my-4 justify-content-md-center">
            <label class="col-lg-3" for="regName">NOMBRE</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="regName" placeholder="SEGÚN APARECE EN EL DNI/PASAPORTE" name="regName">
            <div class="invalid-feedback ">El nombre es un campo obligatorio </div>
        </div>
       <div class="row my-4 justify-content-md-center">
            <label class="col-lg-3" for="reg_birthday">CONFIRMA TU TALLA</label>
            <select class="form-select" id="talla" nombre="talla" aria-label="Default select example">
                <option value="xs">XS</option>
                <option value="s">S</option>
                <option value="m" selected>M</option>
                <option value="L">L</option>
                <option value="xl">XL</option>
                <option value="xxl">XXL</option>
            </select>
        </div>      
        <div class="login_cb justify-content-md-center">
                <label for="reg_allergies">ALERGIAS, INTOLERANCIAS O DIETAS ESPECIALES</label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input " id="reg_allergies" name="allergies" >
        </div>          
        <button id="register_button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >GUARDAR</button>
    </form>
```

While this is shortened all the other imput fields are working and enclosed within the same div class="row my-4 justify-content-md-center"

In my php i tried checking with:

```
 var_dump($_POST);die;
```

I am able to see there that ALL of the other variables are there except the options
And one more thing. I have some validations before i send the information:

```
$('#login_registro_form').submit(function(e) {
//My validations for the rest of the form
        console.log($('#talla').val()); //THIS IS ACTUALLY SHOWING THE INFORMATION
return (errores.length <= 0 );
    });
```

So the information IS there just before posting it, but for some reason it is not being recognised as part of the form

Edit: I know i can retrieve the information using jquery and send it it by creating a new field, but im trying to understand my html mistake here.

Comment: You have not give that <select> a `name="talla"` attribute, so it is not sent to the PHP code. Only fields with a `name=` attribute are candidates for posting to the PHP code

Comment: Ok, nombre is the spanish word for name. Now i got the typo. Thanks

Comment: Your select element needs a name attribute. Yours is written in Spanish "nombre" it should be `name` in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not given the `<select>` element a `name="talla"` **attribute**, Therefore it is not sent to the PHP code. Only fields with a `name=` **attribute** can send data to **PHP Code**.

Comment: Yes, mother language is spanish for me so my brain read "name" where i used "nombre" quite a dumb thing but i was unable to see it.

Comment: @Mbotet Yeah it happens some time :)